# What is the fastest way to load a text file to an access Database?

Tags: c#, ms-access, file, import

I have Text file that contains data separated with a comma `,`.

How do I load this to access in the fastest way?

The Text file contains 200,000 rows.

I work with C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access is quite happy to import CSV files, it can be done through an SQL statement.

```
SELECT ID,Field1 INTO NewTable 
FROM [Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\Docs\].Some.CSV
```

See: [Speed up insert mdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248604/speed-up-insert-mdb/2248978#2248978)

Answer (score -1):

well if you have 2 hard drive's try placing the text file on one hard drive and the access database on one hard drive, you could then try to use 2 threads one for reading and one for writing..

Answer (score -1):

the fastest and hackiest way I know would be to import the data to excel and then cut and paste it into the table in Access. If you need something programatically then I am sure a quick search could find a way to read a CSV file in C#. From there you just need to open a C# data source and plow the data in.

Can you be more specific about your problem...