# Difference between objRecordset.MoveNext and loop?

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, ado

My code reads in lines of a .csv file (comma separated file) and assigns each value to a local variable.  After I have done some logic and stored the values in a table, I read in the next line of the .csv file and repeat the process.  My question is what is the  objRecordset.MoveNext doing compared to the loop.  Here is my code, some of it has been removed to focus on the loop and objrecordset.MoveNext.

```
objconnection.Open 'connection string'
objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & ThisFileName & "]", objconnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText 'select all text lines from the file

Do While Not objRecordset.EOF 'read lines until end of file

'Clear out all the local objects so prior values aren't left there
    SampleName = ""
    DateTimeAcquired = ""
    Analyte = ""
    Concentration = ""
    Units = ""

   'reads in each value according to column name and save to variable'
      SampleName = objRecordset.Fields("Sample Name").Value
      DateTimeAcquired = objRecordset.Fields("Date and Time Acquired").Value
      Analyte = objRecordset.Fields("Element Full Name").Value
      Concentration = objRecordset.Fields("Concentration").Value
      Units = objRecordset.Fields("Units").Value

'Logic done on variables'
        objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

I am using Access 2010 VBA

Comment: If you leave out `objRecordset.MoveNext`, you will never get to the end of the recordset, so you will have a continuous loop. Why are you doing all this work? You can update from a CSV with SQL.

Comment: How can I import from a .csv with SQL?

Comment: For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400090/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-load-a-text-file-to-an-access-database/2400930#2400930

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objRecordset.MoveNext` serves two purposes

1. As an Exit condition
2. Move to Next record

If you don't have `objRecordset.MoveNext` then the loop will continue infinitely since it doesn't reach `objRecordset.EOF` and rather stays on `same record`