# Bulk Insert Access from Dataset

Tags: c#, ms-access, dao, bulkinsert

I have been following the code from 
[Bulk Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070011/writing-large-number-of-records-bulk-insert-to-access-in-net-c)
However I am getting an exception of Invalid Argument at 
**AccesssRecordset.Update();**
or
**rs.Update();**

It takes two arguments Int UpdateType and bool Force

```
public void BulkExportToAccess(DataTable dtOutData, String DBPath, String TableNm) 
{ 
DAO.DBEngine dbEngine = new DAO.DBEngine();
Boolean CheckFl = false;

try
{
    DAO.Database db = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(DBPath);
    DAO.Recordset AccesssRecordset = db.OpenRecordset(TableNm);
    DAO.Field[] AccesssFields = new DAO.Field[dtOutData.Rows.Count];

    //Loop on each row of dtOutData
    for (Int32 rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < dtOutData.Rows.Count; rowCounter++)
    {
        AccesssRecordset.AddNew();
        //Loop on column
        for (Int32 colCounter = 0; colCounter < dtOutData.Columns.Count; colCounter++)
        {
            // for the first time... setup the field name.
            if (!CheckFl)

          AccesssFields[colCounter] =                                               
          AccesssRecordset.Fields[dtOutData.Columns[colCounter].ColumnName];
            AccesssFields[colCounter].Value = dtOutData.Rows[rowCounter][colCounter];
        }

        AccesssRecordset.Update();
        CheckFl = true;
    }

    AccesssRecordset.Close();
    db.Close();
}
finally
{
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dbEngine);
    dbEngine = null;
 }
 }
```

Can anyone help

Thank you

Comment: Where is the data coming from on its way to MS Access?

Comment: Can you post your code? There's a lot of code on the link, would help if you could post the relevant code and point out where you are getting an error

Comment: @Remou I didnt get you But i'll try to explain the DsoutData is coming from Access and the TableNm is the name of the table Which is in my Mdb Hope it helps

Comment: Are you getting your error on the first iteration of your loop, or on subsequent iterations? Have you tried moving `AccesssRecordset.Update();` to the outside of your for loop?

Comment: Yes I am getting Error at the First Iteration..Also I have deleted all the rows from the table in which I have to insert

Comment: The problem is that there is almost never any reason to run code such as included in the link. You can simply run SQL to update one table from another, create a table from another, copy a table from one Mdb to another mdb, etc, and across multiple database and text types. It seems that you want to copy a table from one mdb to another, is that correct?

Comment: Yes I am trying to do BUlk Insert into MSAccess

Comment: Where are you actually adding to the recordset? Apart from the new row at `AccesssRecordset.AddNew();`, you add data to your AccessFields array, put then never put this data into the row, am I missing something?

Comment: Also, as @Remou said, there is no need to use code like this, you can indeed run SQL to update one table from another.

Comment: I changed the Force type to False there was no error But the data wasn't inserted any Clue?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the `OpenRecordset` creates a [`Recordset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821467.aspx) object. The `UpdateType` it's looking for is from the [`UpdateTypeEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196186.aspx); you can just send a 1. And as far as the `Force` goes, I think in your case you probably want to send `true`. What that means is if there was somebody else that updated one of those records, their changes would not be considered and possibly lost because your updates would be **forced.**

Comment: I have 103 Columns and 7823 ROws When I enter  AccesssRecordset.Update(1, true); I get an Invalid Argument Error

Comment: @Kyle, are you sure that's where the error is occurring? That's the same error you were getting before - and interestingly enough those parameters are actually *optional*.

Comment: Yes I did the Debugging  and at that same point I am getting Invalid Argument Error