# Updating 3 Rows (fixed) Using 1 UPDATE Statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

So far I have this code updating only 1 row but is there a way to specify the three rows? (3 different ID's)

```
Public Shared Sub UpdatePrice(ByVal NewPrice As Decimal, ByVal id As Integer)

    Dim dtoffenseinfo As New DataTable

    If Not DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection
        DBConnection.Open()
    Else

    End If

    cmd.Connection = DBConnection

    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblStockPrice " & _
                   " SET Price=" & NewPrice & " WHERE id=" & id & ""


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    DBConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

I assume I need 2 more parameters for the other two rows and that would be fine.

Comment: Do you want to set the same price for all three rows?

Comment: Use [`and`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188372.aspx) in your [search condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx) of [where clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx) I'm assuming you are using Ms Sql server as you have not specified your back-end.

Comment: Oh right no, not the same prices. @S. Ahn

Comment: What sql backend are you using?

Comment: @zespri Oops. Just MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one `UPDATE` statement with an appropriate `WHERE` clause to affect multiple records but, if you want to affect each record differently, calling `ExecuteNonQuery` once is not a very good option.  Just create one command with appropriate parameters and then you can set the `Value` of each parameter multiple times to affect multiple records, e.g.

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New SqlCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET Price = @Price WHERE Id = @Id", connection)
    Dim priceParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Money)
    Dim idParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int)

    Dim prices = {12.45, 132.67, 9.8}
    Dim ids = {1, 19, 56}

    connection.Open()

    For i = 0 To 2
        priceParameter.Value = prices(i)
        idParameter.Value = ids(i)

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I guess there's no escaping using loop. Cheers.

Comment: @user3522506 some people reported that using DAO instead of OLEDB works.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788441/ms-access-batch-update-via-ado-net-and-com-interoperability and here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1256c0c0-f836-4a5c-8772-c3001839d052/bulk-insert-in-ms-access?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: @zespri, there's no point using DAO in this case. The number of rows being updated in this case is very small so there's no real advantage gained.

Comment: @user3522506, you can add your records to a `DataTable` and set the `RowState` of each `DataRow` to `Modified`, create a data adapter with an appropriate `UpdateCommand` and then save all the changes with a single call to `Update`.  You're not really going to save much, if anything, code-wise and you might well have to use a loop to populate the `DataTable` anyway.