# Import delphi data to access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, import

i have to insert till 30000 record from delphi into MsAccess database using DAO. with normal insert into this take a lot of time > 10 minutes...
I've read there is a procedure to insert directly from txt file (using adoCommand) but i don't understand how to made it.

Someone can help me?

Thank you for your help

Comment: [Googling "ms access bulk insert"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+access+bulk+insert) turns up [this SO post from someone using DotNet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070011/writing-large-number-of-records-bulk-insert-to-access-in-net-c), maybe it gets you somewhere. The term you want is *bulk insert*.

Comment: It's worse ;-) Googling "delphi access bulk insert" shows that your question is a duplicate.

Comment: And for those who happen-upon this thread . . . when I see "bulk inserts that take a long time," I usually find that the inserts are being performed one-by-one and with "automatic transactions."  In other words, a new transaction is started, *one* statement is executed, and the transaction `COMMIT`s.  What you want to do is to start a transaction explicitly, insert a bunch of rows, then commit.  (This is *drastically* important in SQLite . . . )  "Thirty thousand rows" is actually a fairly *minuscule* amount of data ...