# Insert .CVS data into access DB using VB.NET 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I would like to insert the content of a .CVS file into an Access .mdb database using VB.NET. I know there's a lot of examples of this but they usually use TSQL commands (like the BULK command) that - as far as I know - I can't use with Jet 4.0.

The columns in the file are separated by semicolon just like that :

9.00;test colonne 2;2013

This is the first time I have to work with that kind of files and have no idea where to start. Please be gentle with me :D.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: are you looking to insert into an existing access database or are you wanting to simply convert from csv to mdb?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248604/speed-up-insert-mdb/2248978#2248978. It is easy enough to insert with non-standard delimiters and a schema.ini

Comment: I want to insert it into an existing .mdb. It will an incremential database, and my boss just told me that the file name will change everyday (since the data from the CVS file will be added to the database on a daily basis). 
Remou, what do I have write in this schema.ini? It's not clear what's needed in that file.

Comment: Well, it looks like I'll have to bring some work home tonight. I was wondering, in the schema.ini I have to enter the name of the file I will be working on. However the name of the file will constantly change from day to day, is there a way to avoid writing that file? I will be able to determine the name of the future files since it will based on the name of the machine and the day of creation.

Comment: If you use @ + username, a person will be notified, so @remou will get my attention. You need the name of the file, but you can write the schema.ini file very easily before you start the import: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx, or you can rename the text file.

Comment: I'm now able to add data to the database using a normal connection string, no need to add extension properties (at least not for me). However, I'm now running into a SQL problem as I'm only able to create a new table for my data (I'm not good at SQL'ing so I just used the SELECT INTO instruction).
So to sum up, I'm combining all .csv files into a single .txt file and add a header for the columns,  and then add it to database using SELECT INTO from the 1st. Result: I'm now having a SQL problem because the select into overwrite my data :D.

Comment: What you need is an append query: `INSERT INTO ...` Here are a few references: [`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx) ---
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx) ---
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @Remou Thanks I can finally add my values to the database. I'll post later how I managed to make it work :).

Comment: Great! And happy hunting.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the LINQ to CSV library. I have had much success with it in the past.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library